# How to create an Updating React Table from Server response

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, response

The aim is to create a table by server response.

The Code of response (It gives an array):

```
function Parse() {
  var store;
  var request = 'http://localhost:3001/Products?city=0&shop=0';
  axios.get(request)
    .then(function(response) { 
      store = response.data; 
      return store;  //        <--- Q1
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      () => { cl("Server Error: ", error) };
    });
 }
```

And now I need to create a table:

```
class ProductsTable extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      store: []
    };
  }

  render() {
    // this.setState({store:Parse()})  //<---  Q2
    return (
      <div className='ProductsTable'>
        <p>{this.state.store}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

Q1- is returning the store (array of items)

Q2- can not use there setState because it makes loop.

And the Button that need to make a request to the server and update the table:

```
class LeftPanel extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      store: []
    };
  }

  render() {
    var funct = function(elem) {
      <ProductsTable />
    }
    return (
      <div className='PanelContent Center'>
        <CreateButtons funct={funct} />
      </div>
    );
  }
};

class CreateButtons extends React.Component {
  render() {
    var rows = [];
    rows.push(<TheButton source={source} funct={this.props.funct}/>);
    return(<div className='MenuTable Center'>{rows}</div>);
  }
};

class TheButton extends React.Component {
  render() {
    elem = <button onClick={this.props.funct}></button>;
    return <div>{elem}</div>;
  }
};
```

But I don't know how to make it in a one working context.
Where should I put setState, and how can I make it updating? Thank you.

I found much information about it in search, but I cannot make it work in my project - I don't have enough understanding of the React structure.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

First make `ProductsTable` and `TheButton` dumb components (no state). Keep `Parse()` as a helper function, but rename it to `fetchData()`.

```
function fetchData() {
  return axios.get('http://localhost:3001/Products?city=0&shop=0')
    .then(response => response.data); 
    .catch((err) => { cl("Server Error: ", err); throw err; });
}

class ProductsTable extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className='ProductsTable'>
        <p>{this.props.products}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
};

class TheButton extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.props.onClick} />
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

Then put the control logic in `LeftPanel`, the parent object.

```
class LeftPanel extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.getData = this.getData.bind(this);
    this.state = { store: [] };
  }

  getData() {
    fetchData().then((data) => this.setState({ store: data }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='PanelContent Center'>
        <div className='MenuTable Center'>
          <TheButton onClick={this.getData} />
        </div>
        <ProductsTable products={this.state.store} />
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

You may need to change some details to fit your specific needs.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Yes, I can see what you are doing, but the problam is that LeftPanel is not perent of ProductsTable. LeftPanel just has TheButton, but ProductsTable is in other component (Main). And I can not run the function from other component. The structure is like that (Root is all page): Root->Main->ProductsTable; Root->LeftPanel->TheButton; And TheButton.onClick - ProductsTable should be updated

Comment: Then you can use the same approach, but put the logic in the `<Root>`. Otherwise, you can use Redux, which is a library for handling this sort of thing. It's used widely in the React ecosystem and easy to learn (great docs).